# STTwitter timeout issue with verifyCredentialsWithSuccessBlock in iOS 9

Tags: ios, ios9, twitter-oauth, xcode7, sttwitter

I am trying to fetch tweets for a particular account using [STTwitter](https://github.com/nst/STTwitter) but getting connection timeout error in **iOS 9** for **verifyCredentialsWithSuccessBlock** method.
I am getting the tweets properly in iOS 8.4 but having trouble in iOS 9.
There is no issue in performing login with twitter using STTWitter.
Following is my code:

```
STTwitterAPI *twitter = [STTwitterAPI twitterAPIAppOnlyWithConsumerKey:_consumerKeyTextField
                                                                consumerSecret:_consumerSecretTextField];

[twitter verifyCredentialsWithSuccessBlock:^(NSString *bearerToken) {
 [twitter getUserTimelineWithScreenName:@"Ointeractive"
                     successBlock:^(NSArray *statuses) {

       self.statuses=[NSArray arrayWithArray:statuses];
       Reachability* wifiReach = [Reachability reachabilityForLocalWiFi];

       NetworkStatus netStatus = [wifiReach currentReachabilityStatus];
       if  (netStatus==ReachableViaWiFi) {
            [self updateTwitterLabelAndImage];
            [self addSwipeToTwitterLabel];
       }
    } errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
      // ...

      NSLog(@"-- %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }];

 } errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
 }];
```

Following is the error that I'm getting:

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x13889ca50 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.}
```

I tried increasing the timeout interval and also tried disabling the App Transport Security using instructions in [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/technotes/App-Transport-Security-Technote/) doc but still no luck. Is there any solution to this or will I have to discard STTwitter and switch to twitter integration using fabric?

Comment: Please ensure you're running the latest STTwitter version available from GitHub by using git pull. Also, please use the verifyCredentialsWithUserSuccessBlock method instead of the deprecated verifyCredentialsWithSuccessBlock.

Comment: Thanks @nst ... upgrading to the latest version of STTwitter and using the verifyCredentialsWithUserSuccessBlock method solved my issue. Getting the tweets now. Thanks :)